# Export data points from Prometheus for visualization with third party monitoring

Tags: prometheus, promql

We are currently trying to export data points from Prometheus for visualization with own dashboard software.
Anyone can help that how can we export data points from Prometheus?
In other words, how Grafana can export data points from Prometheus and then visualize them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the [Prometheus API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) ?

Comment: No, I want to access raw time series data but unfortunately, Prometheus doesn’t support raw data export at the moment.
However, I know that I can export the needed time series data via /query API. In this case, I need to use utility for accessing data points in json response.